# postgresql: row aggregation on a multi table query with distinct on

Tags: database, postgresql

i have a somewhat complex pair of queries that i am trying to push together functionally.

The first is a **(survey query)** that is going to pick various demographic and visit information from 6 tables.  its centered round a visit id number on the visit table it returns a row for each visit ID and each visits demographic info

the second query **(procedure query)** joins 5 tables and is also joined to the visit table.  it returns a line for each procedure code instead of each visit.

I am trying to array the procedures for each visit into 5 seperate columns and include this into the results for the survey query.

the current procedure query that we use.

```
Procedure Query

SELECT D
   DISTINCT ON ("public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num, 
                    "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_code)

"public".visit.visit_id AS "Patient ID",
("public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_code) AS "Procedure Code"

FROM
"public".patient_procedure
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_desc_master_codes ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_cpcode = "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_group_cpt_code ON "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id = "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_group_snomed_codes ON "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id = "public".procedure_group_snomed_codes.pgrpsnomed_pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".visit ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num = "public".visit.visit_id
LEFT JOIN "public".physician_table1 ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_proc_phy1 = "public".physician_table1.phys1_num


ORDER BY
"public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num
```

.

the results look like

```
Patient id   procedure code
-----------|------------------------
     1     |    A34
     1     |    B23
     1     |    C43
     2     |    F12 
     3     |    A34
     3     |    E65       
     4     |    T55       
     4     |    U67
```

.

I have tried using ***Array_agg*** on the procedure codes using the following varient

.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON ("public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num)
    "public".visit.visit_id AS "Patient ID",
     array_agg("public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_code) AS "Procedure Code"

FROM
"public".patient_procedure
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_desc_master_codes ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_cpcode = "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_group_cpt_code ON "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id = "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_group_snomed_codes ON "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id = "public".procedure_group_snomed_codes.pgrpsnomed_pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".visit ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num = "public".visit.visit_id
LEFT JOIN "public".physician_table1 ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_proc_phy1 = "public".physician_table1.phys1_num


group by
"public".visit.visit_id,
"public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num,
"public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_code


ORDER BY
"public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num
```

using the array_agg function the results look like this, duplicating the first value.  i presume for each time that patient id occurs in the table/results.

.
.

```
 Patient id   procedure code
-----------|------------------------
     1     |    {A34,A34,A34,A34,A34}
     1     |    {B23,B23,B23,B23,B23,}
     1     |    {C43,C43}
     2     |    {F12,F12}
     3     |    {A34}
     3     |    {E65,E65,E65,E65,E65,E65,E65,E65,}
     4     |    {T55,T55,T55,T55,}
```

the survey query, i'd like to shove the procedures into the middle

```
select 
distinct on ("public".visit.visit_id)
rpad('1.6.1', 5, '') AS "Survey Designator",
rpad('1.6.1', 5, '') AS "Client ID",
"public".profile.prof_c_ip1lastname AS "Last Name",
left("public".profile.prof_c_ip1midname,1) AS "Middle Initial",
"public".profile.prof_c_ip1firstname AS "First Name",
"public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_addr1 AS "Address 1",
"public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_addr2 AS "Address 2",
"public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_city AS "City",
"public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_state AS "State",


CASE 
WHEN "public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_zip = 0 THEN ''
ELSE "public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_zip::text
END AS "ZIP Code",


CASE 
WHEN "public".profile.prof_c_arpphone = 0 THEN ''
ELSE "public".profile.prof_c_arpphone::text 
END AS "Telephone Number",


CASE WHEN "public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_cell = 0 THEN ''
ELSE "public".profile.prof_c_ip1p_cell::text
END AS "Mobile Number",

rpad('1.6.1', 5, '') AS "MS-DRG",


CASE "public".profile.prof_c_arpsex
when 'M' THEN '1'
WHEN 'F' THEN '2'
ELSE 'M'
END AS "Gender",

to_char("public".visit.visit_date_of_birth, 'MMDDYYYY') AS "Date of Birth",



case LOWER("public".profile.prof_c_ip1language_code)
WHEN 'eng' Then '0'
WHEN 'spa' then '1'
ELSE 'U'
END AS "Preferred Language Code",

"public".visit.visit_mr_num AS "Medical Record Number",
"public".visit.visit_id as "Unique Id",
"public".physician_table1.phys1_npi AS "Attending Physician NPI",
"public".physician_table1.phys1_name AS "Attending Physician Name",

CASE "public".ip_visit_1.ipv1_origin
WHEN '1' THEN '1'
WHEN '2' THEN '2'
WHEN '3' THEN '6'
WHEN '5' THEN '8'
ELSE '9'
END AS "Admission Source",

to_char("public".visit.visit_admit_date, 'MMDDYYYY') AS "Visit or Admit Date",
to_char("public".visit.visit_disch_date, 'MMDDYYYY') AS "Discharge Date",


CASE WHEN "public".ip_visit_1.ipv1_p_email LIKE '%@%'
THEN "public".ip_visit_1.ipv1_p_email ELSE ''
END AS "Email", 


CASE "public".visit.visit_admit_phy_key
when '000215' then '1518958503'
when '002515' then '1770546756'
when '003700' then '1255362448'
else ''
end as "Hospitalist 1",

CASE "public".ip_visit_1.ipv1_phy2
when '000215' then '1518958503'
when '002515' then '1770546756'
when '003700' then '1255362448'
else ''
end as "Hospitalist 2",


case "public".er_log.cnerlog_admdt
when '0001-01-01' then 'N'
else 'Y'
end as "ER_ADMIT",

--somehow get procedures in here,


 case "public".profile.prof_c_ip1expired_dt
 when '0001-01-01' then 'N'
 when null then 'N'
 else 'Y'
End as "Deceased Flag",
rpad('N', 1, '') AS "State Regulation Flag",

case when "public".visit.visit_date_of_birth > ("public".visit.visit_admit_date - interval '29' day) then 'Y'
else 'N' 
end as "Newborn patient",



rpad('$', 1, '') AS "E.O.R Indicator"
FROM
"public".visit
INNER JOIN "public".profile ON "public".profile.prof_c_arpmrnum = "public".visit.visit_mr_num
INNER JOIN "public".physician_table1 ON "public".visit.visit_admit_phy_key = "public".physician_table1.phys1_num
INNER JOIN "public".ip_visit_1 ON "public".ip_visit_1.ipv1_num = "public".visit.visit_id
left JOIN "public".patient_procedure ON "public".visit.visit_id = "public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num
left JOIN "public".procedure_desc_master_codes ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_cpcode = "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id
left  JOIN "public".procedure_group_cpt_code ON "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id = "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_pdescm_id
left JOIN "public".er_log ON "public".er_log.cnerlog_patnum = "public".visit.visit_id

order BY
"public".visit.visit_id asc

limit 10000
```

what is a way to have procedures included into the second query?  doesn't even have to be fast as the query is going to be run a weekly basis

thanks

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
added edit
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

the below aggregated the row returns on the procedure code .  got a lot of duplicates in the aggregated column, but that's still okay.  i'll figure that out next

```
SELECt 
"public".visit.visit_id as "visit ID",
string_agg("public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_code::text, ', ' ) AS "CPT4/HCPCS Code"

FROM
"public".patient_procedure
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_desc_master_codes ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_cpcode = "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_group_cpt_code ON "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id = "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".visit ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num = "public".visit.visit_id

WHERE
"public".patient_procedure.pproc_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-31' AND
"public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num NOT LIKE 'C%'

GROUP BY
"public".visit.visit_id
ORDER BY
"public".visit.visit_id
```

this works even better, puts column into an array value and removes duplicates with array_agg(distinct "value")

```
SELECt 
"public".visit.visit_id as "visit ID",
array_agg(distinct "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_code::text ) AS "CPT4/HCPCS Code"

FROM
"public".patient_procedure
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_desc_master_codes ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_cpcode = "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".procedure_group_cpt_code ON "public".procedure_desc_master_codes.pdescm_id = "public".procedure_group_cpt_code.pgrpcpt_pdescm_id
LEFT JOIN "public".visit ON "public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num = "public".visit.visit_id

WHERE
"public".patient_procedure.pproc_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-31' AND
"public".patient_procedure.pproc_visit_num NOT LIKE 'C%'

GROUP BY
"public".visit.visit_id
ORDER BY
"public".visit.visit_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I see problems like this I tend to think that things are being more complex than they need to be.  Chances are if we try to just incorporate the two queries together performance will be poor and maintainability will not be optimal.

When things are not working right with Distinct On and aggregates, chances are you wanted a `GROUP BY` instead.  Note that these do two totally different things but `GROUP BY` plays much better with aggregates.

In a complex case like this there are some important shortcuts to be aware of:

- when you decide what table forms the atomic part of the aggregation, you can `group by` primary keys of these tables and the tables referencing them outward, saving you the need to group on every column used.
- This will also catch certain ambiguities or problems in database design that you may have to handle manually.

Remember also that with PostgreSQL you also have window functions (which are aggregates applied incrementally) and common table expressions which can be helpful in these cases as well.

So my recommendation is to start mapping out the relations on paper, figure out the sort of data you want, determine what table you are using as the base of the aggregation (i.e where one row from that table means one row in your output) and then look at this using `group by` instead of `distinct on.`

If this isn't sufficient then having mapped out the data and what you want out, you will be in a better position to ask a question on how to get what you want from SQL.

Comment: mostly venting-->> so I'm going through and trying out your suggestions.  every time i dive into this database the more it becomes obvious it was designed and built by people not much more skilled than I, which is not very.  Every single table has at least 3 keys. multiply by 4200 distinct tables.  .   .   also i am trying out your group by on the keys, did not know that was a thing i could do, and it seems like it may be pushing my query in the right direction.